# Reg-ex to match statsD Format

Tags: java, regex, statsd

I am using the following reg-ex to match StatsD data format -

```
^[\w.]+:.+\|.\|#(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*$
```

This satisfies any of the following formats -

```
performance.os.disk:1099511627776|g|#region:us-west-1,datacenter:us-west-1a
```

or

```
performance.os.disk:1099511627776|g|#
```

or

```
performance.os.disk:1099511627776|g|#region:us-west-1
```

But I am unable to match it against -

```
datastore.reads:9876|ms
```

Any help?

RegEx 101 to try - https://regex101.com/r/H8vQTa/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^[\w.]+:[^|]+\|[^|]+(?:\|#(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*)?$
               ^^^^^^^^                             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8vQTa/2)

The point is that you only match any char with `.` between two `|`s, I suggest matching 1 or more chars other than `|` there, and make the rest optional by wrapping `\|#(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*` within an optional non-capturing group, `(?:...)?`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w.]+` - 1+ word or `.` chars
- `:` - a colon
- `[^|]+`  - a negated character class matching 1+ non-`|` chars
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `[^|]+` - 1+ chars other than `|`
- `(?:\|#(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\|#` - `|#` substring
  - `(?:[\w.]+:[^,\n]+(?:,|$))*` - 0 or more consecutive repetitions of

    - `[\w.]+:` - 1+ word or `.` chars and then `:`
    - `[^,\n]+` - 1+ chars other than LF (I guess it is used for debug purposes here) and `,`
    - `(?:,|$)` - `,` or end of string
- `$` - end of string.